# Replace certain characters in a string from array values

Tags: php, eloquent

I've got an array :

```
$arr = [5, "David"];
```

I've got a query :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ? AND user_name = ?";
```

I want to create a logger query that takes these 2 and returns the query, manually.

```
logger($query, $arr); // returns : SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 5 AND user_name = 'David'
```

I'm using eloquent's capsule manager.

I tried doing something like this but it doesn't replace anything :

```
function logger($query, $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        is_numeric($a) ? str_replace("?",$a,$query) : str_replace("?","'".$a."'",$query);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Why isn't this code working?

Comment: What is `$params` ?

Comment: @B001ᛦ typo, fixed.

Comment: The actual question should be "why do you need that"? Why don't you use mysql logs?

Comment: erm, I don't know much about php, but aren't strings immutable. eg you need to assign the reference

Comment: @B001ᛦ I'm not looking for alternatives or "you should do it this or that way", I'm trying to understand why doesn't this code work as is.

Comment: @johnny5 where exactly would you pass the query as a reference?

Comment: see @nicks answer hes assigning the query reference

Comment: @johnny5 he removed his answer. People are downvoting but I still didn't get any useful tip :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it, by using `str_replace_first` and assiging the value into a variable.

```
        foreach($params as $a) {
            $query = is_numeric($a) ? str_replace_first("?",$a,$query,1) : str_replace_first("?","'".$a."'",$query);
        }
        return $query;
```

`str_replace_first` :

```
function str_replace_first($search_for, $replace_with, $in) {
  $pos = strpos($in, $search_for);
  if($pos === false) {
    return $in;
  } else {
    return substr($in, 0, $pos) . $replace_with . substr($in, $pos + strlen($search_for), strlen($in));
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you find that function? It's not standard PHP

Comment: @Nick yeah I added the function I created, could you tell me what do you think of it? I upvoted your answer nonetheless.

Comment: That looks like a pretty efficient way to do it. Only thing I would say is you don't need the length parameter for the second call to `substr`. Also you might want to look at `substr_replace` as a substitute for the whole line e.g. `substr_replace($in, $replace_with, $pos, strlen($search_for));`

Answer (score 1):

[`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) does not modify its argument, it returns the modified value instead. So you need to assign its output to a variable. However the problem is that `str_replace` will replace all occurrences of the pattern at the same time. Instead, you can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), which has a `limit` parameter which can be used to tell it to replace only one occurrence of the pattern for each call. I've used a pattern for `preg_replace` that will ensure that only a `?` on its own in the query will be replaced, in case there is a question mark elsewhere e.g. in a column alias. Change your function to this:

```
function logger($query, $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        $query = is_numeric($a) ? 
            preg_replace("/(?<=\s)\?(?=\s|$)/", $a, $query, 1) : 
            preg_replace("/(?<=\s)\?(?=\s|$)/", "'$a'", $query, 1);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 5 AND user_name = 'David'
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/nL5oI)

Comment: It's not going to work for more than one variable though. str_replace replaces all instances of the needle.

Comment: @ChrisWhite thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected the code.

Comment: @Equgonyka take note of Chris' comment; I've edited the code to solve that problem.